# Is Ubuntu a bad distro for a standalone mysql database server?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I read an article here :

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/12/08/which-linux-distribution-for-mysql-server/

> On the other end there are Debian and Ubuntu. Both use tool called
>   dpkg for package management. There isn’t a month that I log in to a
>   system based on either distribution where there are no issues with
>   packages consistency. Unfinished installations, unresolved conflicts
>   are so common that it’s just beyond simple negligence. The packaging
>   system is just not robust enough. Another problem is that one broken
>   package may block you from installing or uninstalling anything else.
>   Imagine that someone left system in such shape, you prepared for
>   downtime, stopped MySQL and… error – text editor has not been properly
>   installed, so you cannot upgrade MySQL either until the problem is
>   fixed. In a stressful situation when downtime clock ticks – annoying
>   at best

We prefer Ubuntu server because of familiarity and Ubuntu also being development environment.
Questions:

1. Is Ubuntu used commonly in production for a mysql database server ?
2. Is it worth the trouble ever to have one distro eg Ubuntu in web server, and another say Red Hat in database server ? Or Is a homogenous server pool a better choice ?

Comment: This isn't something that has a correct answer.  As such, it might not be a good fit for a ServerFault query.

Comment: @EightBitTony I agree, but it would be better for me to know viewpoint of fellow sysadmins and then make a call. Serverfault platform suits my requirement well.

Comment: I agree with @EightBitTony, but since we're on an anecdotal kick here, I have ~20 Ubuntu (10.04 LTS primarily) in production and _never_ have had an issue with `dpkg` or `apt-get` when dealing with official `apt` sources.  Come to think of it, I don't recall ever having an issue, only with a botched upgrade years ago with 6.06, but that was my fault.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes.
2. If you are comfortable with administrating two different distributions, then it is no problem.

By choosing one standard distribution for both web and database servers you will see that it will probably be a bit easier to maintain.